# repeating a column value

Tags: sql

I have a date table which has a column defined as first day of the week. This value will always be the first day of the month or on Thursday. Where I am stuck is repeating the first day of the week on the proceeding rows so that I can group the data properly. The table looks like this

[image]

So for the dates 1/3/2014 - 1/8/2014 I need to populate 1/2/2014 as the FirstDateOfWeekFullDate and so on for the next first day of the week.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by "populate" you want to change the table?

Comment: also you need to tell us what platform you are using -- the answer is different for sql-server, mysql, oracle, db2, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql-server and other platforms that support the LAG windowing function you could get the results you wish (via select) like this:

```
SELECT FullDate, CalendarYear, IsFirstDayOfWeek, 
       COALESCE(FirstDateOfWeekFullDate,
         LAG(FirstDateOfWeekFullDate,1) OVER (ORDER BY FullDate ASC),
         LAG(FirstDateOfWeekFullDate,2) OVER (ORDER BY FullDate ASC),
         LAG(FirstDateOfWeekFullDate,3) OVER (ORDER BY FullDate ASC),
         LAG(FirstDateOfWeekFullDate,4) OVER (ORDER BY FullDate ASC),
         LAG(FirstDateOfWeekFullDate,5) OVER (ORDER BY FullDate ASC),
         LAG(FirstDateOfWeekFullDate,6) OVER (ORDER BY FullDate ASC))
       as FirstDateOfWeekFullDate
FROM putYourTableNameHere
```

You could also do it with a join.  I think LAG will be faster -- but I say this without testing both.

Comment: I apologize, this is SQL Server (T-SQL).

Comment: Hogan's proposal works great! Thank you for the help!

Comment: This isn't a proposal -- its an answer :)  A proposal would be -- "I'll solve this for you for $1,000,000"

Comment: @FrankK: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As it relates to the value in `FullDate`, you can use a `CASE` statement to modify results based on the values in that field. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
FullDate,
CalendarYear,
IsFirstDayOfWeek,
CASE WHEN datepart(DW,FullDate) > 5 THEN FullDate - datepart(DW,FullDate) + 5
     WHEN datepart(DW,FullDate) < 5 THEN FullDate - datepart(DW,FullDate) - 2
     ELSE FullDate END as [FirstDateOfWeekFullDate]
FROM YourDB..YourTable
```

This is valid in T-SQL. I'm not sure which RDBMS you're using, but there are similar functions available in all of them.

**EDIT**

To include the first day of the month is a little more complex, but still doable with a case statement. The `CASE` example below checks the FullDate value to see if it is greater than or equal to the 5th Thursday of the current month (if 5 exist), then the 4th Thursday, then the 3rd, then the 2nd, then the 1st. If it is less than the date value of the 1st Thursday, then it defaults to the 1st day of the month, regardless of what weekday it is.

It looks like a lot of code, but it's really just a lot of repetition of `DateAdd(day, (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))`, which is just calculating the first Thursday of the month.

```
SELECT
FullDate,
CalendarYear,
IsFirstDayOfWeek,
CASE WHEN FullDate >= DateAdd(day, 28 + (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))
                 THEN DateAdd(day, 28 + (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))
     WHEN FullDate >= DateAdd(day, 21 + (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))
                 THEN DateAdd(day, 21 + (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))
     WHEN FullDate >= DateAdd(day, 14 + (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))
                 THEN DateAdd(day, 14 + (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))
     WHEN FullDate >= DateAdd(day,  7 + (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))
                 THEN DateAdd(day,  7 + (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))
     WHEN FullDate >= DateAdd(day,      (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))
                 THEN DateAdd(day,      (12 - DatePart(DW, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0)))%7, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, FullDate),0))
     ELSE FullDate - datepart(D,FullDate) + 1
END as [FirstDateOfWeekFullDate]
FROM YourDB..YourTable
```

Comment: I don't think this will work his BR are more complex -- *"This value will always be the first day of the month or on Thursday."*

Comment: Hmm, good point. It could still be resolved with a case statement, albeit a slightly more complex one. I would need to see more sample data with some example rows that don't match the pattern already provided.

Comment: And what is a case statement, but some fancy syntax around a join -- the best source of the BR is the table itself (since he does not really provide them) -- that is why I say it could be done with a join.  It would take some complicated query work to make the sub-query and join work, but it could be done -- in any case LAG will be faster because the optimizer can pull values in a single pass.

Comment: You are right, however not everyone can use `LAG` - in T-SQL for example, this function is only available in SSMS 2014 and higher. It never hurts to have multiple options. :)

Comment: the BR breaks down as "the first day of a week will always be Thursday but a full week will never cross over into a new month, hence the start date of the week will always be Thursday OR the first of the month. I would be happy to provide a table, but the easiest way is to set a bit flag for every Thursday or first of month. When I ran Hogan's solution, it accounted for the shorter weeks due to rolling into a new month

Comment: So in the case of 1/30/2014 (which is a Thursday), you have a 2-day week covering just 1/30 - 1/31, and then start the next week at 2/1/2014 (Saturday) because it is the 1st of the month, and then start another week again on 2/6/2014 (the next Thursday). Is that all correct?

Comment: You gave valuable content and invested a considerable amount of time, here is one of my 40 daily upvotes.